# General solution of ODE cos function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this exercise but i'm not coming forward.

> I must find a general solution of $$ x' = \frac{1}{\cos(x+t)} -1. $$

Every Tip would be helpful. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
Observe, we can rewrite the given ODE as.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x+t)  =\frac{1}{\cos(x+t)}
$$

Comment: So you mean I need to substitue $x+t$ with a new variable.

Comment: @Mathgamer yes, call $y=x+t$ to get $\frac{dy}{dt}=\sec(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$\int\sec(x+t) dt = \int{\frac{(\tan(x+t) +\sec(x+t))'} {\tan(x+t) +\sec(x+t)} dt} $$

Comment: Cheers Anurag, mobile didn't let me preview :/